# Enum cannot work when reference it cross multi visual studio solution

Tags: c#, enums, reference, solution

I have three solution A, B and C. 
I have an enum in A like this:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
namespace A.Entities
{
    [DataContract]
    public enum Status
    {
        [DataMember]
        Active = 0,

        [DataMember]
        Inactive = 1,
    }
}
```

I reference it in solution B like this:

```
using A.Entities;
namespace B.Entities
{
    public class User
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Status Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In solution C, I use them like this:

```
using B.Entities;
using Status = A.Entities.Status;
namespace C.TestDatas
{
    public class UserTestData
    {
        public static User CreateUser()
        {
            return new User
                   {
                       Status = Status.Active,
                   }
        };
    }
}
```

When I invoke User method, it throw exception:

> Method not found: 'Void B.Entities.User.set_Status(A.Entities.Status)'.

Why? I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: Possibly related, note that you need to decorate enumerations with [`EnumMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), not `DataMember`

Comment: from the code you posted, I dont see set_Status(Status s) method in B.Entities.User - The compiler is correctly complaining if that is the case

Comment: post the code where you are creating the user

Comment: DataMember is not work too. I donot have wcf invoke.

Comment: I dont see set_Status too , I don't know why the compiler post it.

Comment: My create user invoke is UserTestData.CreateUser() .

Comment: set_Status is a compiler generated method for Status property setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem. Your code works fine on my computer (on .NET framework 4.5)

Could you make sure that you project is configured correctly:

1. Both `A` and `B` solutions have reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization`
2. `C` has reference to `A` and `B`. Make sure you don't link the dll from `/Bin` folder, but you have the project reference
3. Hit Clean and Rebuild buttons in Visual Studio.